# bat file get dir path

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have folder  structure:

folder "1" that Contains  "1.1" "1.2" "1.3"
folder "1.1" Contains "1.1.1" "1.1.2"

in the bat file :

```
cd %folderDir%
@echo off
call :treeProcess
goto :eos

:treeProcess

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a:-d/b 2^>nul ') do echo "%%~fa" >>%pathDdfFile%

for /D %%d in (*) do (
   echo %%d >>%pathDdfFile%
echo  %%d
 cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..


)
goto :eof

:eos

cd \
```

I get:

```
1.1 
1.1.1 
1.1.2 
1.2 
1.3
```

but I need:

```
1.1 
1.1\1.1.1 
1.1\1.1.2 
1.2 
1.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of the directories like you desire, you can do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /S /B /A:D /O:N ^| SORT') DO (
    SET tmp=%%G
    ECHO !tmp:%CD%\=!
)
```

This will, if executed from within the folder `1`, give you:

```
1.1
1.1\1.1.1
1.1\1.1.2
1.2
1.3
```

It works by removing the current directory from the output of the `DIR /S /B` command.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get relative paths is using `xcopy /L`, because it returns paths relative to the current directory in case a relative source path is given; `/L` tells to actually not copy:

```
xcopy /L /S /E /I /Y ".\*.*" "%TEMP%\"
```

To avoid the summary line `?? File(s)`, use a simple `find` command to filter it out:

```
xcopy /L /S /E /I /Y ".\*.*" "%TEMP%\" | find ".\"
```

This can finally be parsed by a `for /F` loop to iterate trough every single item:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    xcopy /L /S /E /I /Y ".\*.*" "%TEMP%\" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    echo(%%I
)
```

---

The great advantage of this method is that the system accomplishes the path computations, hence you do not need to write extra code for something the system is anyway already able to do for you.
So no string manipulation activities are needed, delayed expansion is not required, which reduce the overall performance and might even be prone to errors particularly in special cases.